# How to extract date part from a datetime in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime, date

I have a sql query which extract a field of datatype `smalldatetime`. I read this field using datareader, convert it to string and store it in a string variable.

I get the string as **1/1/2012 12:00:00 AM** ,here i want to use only date part of this string and i have nothing to do with the time.

How can i cut only the date from the string and get the output as **1/1/2012**?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may convert string to date type using Date.Parse() and use `ToShortDateString()`

```
Dim dt as Date = Date.Parse(dateString)
Dim dateString=dt.ToShortDateString()
```

As you said the type of field is smalldatetime then use `DataReader.GetDateTime(column_ordinal).ToString("d")` method or `DataReader.GetDateTime(column_ordinal).ToShortDateString()`

Answer (score 4):

You need to *format* the `DateTime` using a [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) for only dates.

```
string dateString = myDate.ToString("d");
```

This is equivalent to:

```
string dateString = myDate.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the string to Date and then get the Date part of the variable:

```
Dim myDateTime as Date = Date.Parse(dateString)
Dim MyDate as Date = myDateTime.Date()
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried with

```
Dim fromdt As String = dtfrom.ToString("d")
```

it didnt worked at all then i tried like this and it worked

```
Dim fromdt As String = dtfrom.Value.ToString("d")
```